# UITabBar with autoresize

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am using a `UITabBar` in an iPhone and iPad app, but autoresizing is not working on the iPad when I go to landscape mode (it works fine on the iPhone).

```
{
    tabBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    tabBarController.delegate=self;
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController1,navController2, navController3,navController4,navController5,nil];
    tabBarController.selectedViewController = navController1;
    imgTab = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768.0,51)];
    [imgTab setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin]; imgTab.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"footerbg.jpg"];
    [tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:imgTab];
    accountImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0,5.0,29.0,29.0)];
    [accountImg setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    accountImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"click11.png"];
    UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0];
    [tabItem setTitle:@"Task"];
    [imgTab addSubview:accountImg];
    staffImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(255,5.0,29.0,29.0)];
    staffImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"spreadsheet11-1.png"];
    UITabBarItem *tabItem1 = [[[tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1];
    [tabItem1 setTitle:@"SpreadSheet"];
    [staffImg setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [imgTab addSubview:staffImg];
    taskImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(370.0,5.0,29.0,29.0)];
    taskImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar2.png"];
    UITabBarItem *tabItem2 = [[[tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2];
    [tabItem2 setTitle:@"Calendar"];
    [taskImg setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [imgTab addSubview:taskImg];
    spreadImg =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(472.0,5.0,29.0,29.0)];
    spreadImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"message22.png"];
    UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [[[tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3];
    [tabItem3 setTitle:@"Message"];
    [spreadImg setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [imgTab addSubview:spreadImg];

}
```

Comment: In ipad views get rotated, but autosizing doesn't work well, or views does not rotate at all?

Comment: You have to provide more information.

Comment: I did this same code in iphone it is working when i do landscape mode but not working in ipad??

Comment: Your code is absolutely unreadable. I **highly** doubt anyone will try understanding it.

Comment: And it doesn't help understanding the problem. Start by answering @IvanAlek 's question.

Comment: i am taking  four view controller and after that i am adding it on navigation and remaining code you can see .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in this code that you are configuring UIAutoresizingMask for your UITabBar, only for items in it.

Comment: but i did it with the image which i am applying on tab bar you can see in my code

Comment: please help me .i am getting trouble